# Header, menu and footer are getting cut off?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Ok, I have a website made on WordPress and have edited the css lots.
The website appears fine but when you shrink the browser the page gets cut off.
This is not a responsive website, The problem is not that scroll bars appear and you need to scroll to see more, the problem is the header, footer and the menu get clipped.

Some of the css code is

```
/*
    Theme Name: thememagic
    Theme URI: http://themeszen.com/thememagic
    Description: A very neat and clean black and white business theme. The theme supports widgets. And features 
    theme-options, threaded-comments and multi-level dropdown menu. A simple and neat typography. This theme is the free version of our pro theme.
    Version: 1.4.10
    Author: Manish Gori
    Author URI: http://themeszen.com
    Tags: black,two-columns,theme-options
    License: GNU General Public License v2.0
    License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
    */

@import "css/reset.css";

    /* general */
    /*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/



a.special {
    font-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

a.special:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

a.special:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a.special:active,
    a.special:hover {
    color: #E6E6E6;
    outline: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
    3
        line-height: 1.5em;
}

a {
    color: #464646;
    outline: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

a:link {
    color: #464646;
}

a:visited {
    color: #464646;
}

a:active,
    a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2.name {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h2.quote {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    font-family: 'Margarine', cursive;
}

h2.shadow {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Margarine', cursive;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Margarine', cursive;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}

hr {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    clear: both;
}

p {
    padding: 0 0 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

ul {
    list-style: square;
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
}
```

The header.php code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>


    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

               <title>  

        <?php 

                 wp_title( '|' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description"; ?>

        </title>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Margarine' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=McLaren|Raleway:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />


    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <!--wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">

    <!--headercontainer-->
    <div id="header_container">

        <!--header-->
        <div id="header">

            <?php if ( ( of_get_option('logo_image') ) != '' ) { ?>
        <div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('logo_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo of_get_option('footer_cr'); ?>" /></a></div><!--logo end-->
    <?php } else { ?>
            <div id="logo2"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></div><!--logo end-->
    <?php } ?>




            </div><!-- header end-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!--header container end-->       

    <div class="clear"></div>

        <!--menu-->
    <div id="menu_container">

        <div id="menubar">

        <?php $navcheck = '' ; ?>

    <?php $navcheck = wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' , 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false ) ); ?>

 <?php  if ($navcheck == '') { ?>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="page_item"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="Home"><?php _e( 'Home', 'thememagic' ); ?></a></li>                
        <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>

    </ul>
<?php } else echo($navcheck); ?>  

    </div>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--menu container end--> 
    <!--menu end-->
```

the site is http://www.shoalhavenspecialas.com/
Please if anyone can help do so for i am struggling with this issue, and needing to get this done in a matter of hours.
Thanks for all your time! :)
I hope you never come a cross a unsolvable problem

Comment: We don't need the entire code. Only what is necessary to demonstrate the problem. That being said, this has been asked more than a handful of times. The solution is to set a minimum width to those elements.

Comment: I only gave what i though was needed, i could have put in the functions.php, index.php, loop.php......

Comment: No, I wasn't asking for MORE code. A good question includes a *minimal* example. Take out code until you cannot take any more out and still demonstrate the problem.

Comment: nor, I was not offering more, just being sarcastic and stating that I thought "the more I give the easier"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the header dimensions, you need to set the width of your `#logo` `<img/>` in CSS inside the container width (964px).

```
#logo img {
    width: 964px;
    height: auto;
}
```

To put everything inside of a box, constrained to the width you like, make these changes:

header.php: Just after the `<body>` opens:

`<div id="wrapperbox">`

footer.php: Just before the `</body>` closes:

`</div>`

style.css:

```
#wrapperbox {
    width: 964px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That changes the image, but the header background color, menu and footer still get removed to the page width?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.. I think. Look at my updated answer and see?

Comment: Would you mind looking at the header.php code above as i cannot find the `<body>` tag

Comment: sorry, is this it `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: Thanks, you fixed the image but every thing else still gets cut off

Comment: You still need to add to style.css (or your stylesheet) the #wrapperbox width declaration :)

Comment: I did, still no result :( :(

Comment: @Stonydallas it's not uploaded to the server then, when I visit http://www.shoalhavenspecialas.com/ and look in the CSS, there's nothing for #wrapperbox still...

Comment: look at this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.shoalhavenspecialas.com/wp-content/themes/thememagic/style.css" />
`

Comment: looks great to me! are you still having any trouble?